# Flattening Table From Excel into Csv with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take the data from a table in excel and put it into a csv in a single row. I have the data imported from excel into a dataframe using pandas, but now, I need to write this data to a csv in a single row. Is this possible to do, and if so, what would the syntax look like generally if I was taking a 50 row 3 column table and flattening it into 1 row 150 column csv table? My code so far is below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filelocation.xlsx',
    sheetname=['pnl1 Data ','pnl2 Data','pnl3 Data','pnl4 Data'],
    skiprows=8, parse_cols="B:D", keep_default_na='FALSE', na_values=['NULL'], header=3)
DataFrame.to_csv("outputFile.csv" )
```

Another question that I would help me understand how to transform this data is, "Is there any way to select a piece of data from a specific row and column"?

Comment: When you flatten a table with multiple columns into a single table, the headers lose all meaning - is this a desired effect?

Comment: i was manually going to put in new headings, so that's okay with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the line_terminator to nothing, like so:

```
df.to_csv('ouputfile.csv', line_terminator=',', index=False, header=False)
```

Or you can translate your dataframe into a numpy array and use the reshape function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = df.values.reshape(1,-1)
```

You can then use `numpy.savetxt()` to save as CSV.

Comment: Is this the only way to flatten out the table? Is there any way to select a piece of data from a specific row and column?

Comment: There might be, but it would defeat the purpose of DataFrames (a DataFrame is a structured table with columns and rows). Better to move to numpy in that case, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to set the line_terminator to ',' so that the final field in one line and the first field in the next line are properly separated?

Comment: Yeah, and you probably also want to set `index=False, header=False` otherwise you get the column and row names all mixed into it.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
df.to_csv("outputFile.csv", line_terminator=',')
```